# Performance Advantages in Storing Documents as JSON in MarkLogic 6

Tags: json, marklogic

If I were to store the same markup in 2 separate documents, one XML, the other JSON, in MarkLogic 6, does MarkLogic automatically convert the JSON equivalent to XML, and index it in that regard, or are both stored in their respective formats?

What I'm getting at is, does MarkLogic store ALL documents as XML, regardless, and simply apply JSON transformations to JSON documents when queried?

If documents are stored in native format, is there any advantage, in terms of performance, to storing documents in JSON over XML?

Below is an example code-snippet:

```
if($outputFormat="json") then (: result in json format :)       
    let $custom-config :=
        let $config := json:config("custom")
        return (map:put($config, "array-element-names",(xs:QName("lp:lesson_plan"), 
                                                        xs:QName("lp:instructional_segment"),
                                                        xs:QName("lp:strand_type"),                                                             
                                                        xs:QName("lp:resource"),
                                                        xs:QName("lp:level"),
                                                        xs:QName("lp:discipline"),
                                                        xs:QName("lp:language"),
                                                        xs:QName("lp:program"),
                                                        xs:QName("lp:grade"),
                                                        xs:QName("res:strand_type"),
                                                        xs:QName("res:resource"),
                                                        xs:QName("res:ISBN"),
                                                        xs:QName("res:level"),
                                                        xs:QName("res:standard"),
                                                        xs:QName("res:secondaryURL"),
                                                        xs:QName("res:grade"),
                                                        xs:QName("res:keyword"))), 
                map:put($config, "whitespace","ignore"),
                map:put($config, "text-value","value"),
                $config) 
    return json:transform-to-json($finalResult, $custom-config)
else (: finalResult in xml format :)        
    $finalResult
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On disk, MarkLogic stores highly compressed C++ data structures that represent hierarchical trees and corresponding indexes. (OK, that’s an over-simplification, but illustrative nonetheless.) There are two places where you as a developer will typically interact with those data structures: 1) building queries and application logic 2) deserializing/serializing data into and out of this internal data model. Today, MarkLogic uses the XML data model (XDM) for the latter and, correspondingly, XQuery, XPath, and XSLT for the former. We chose this stack for several reasons: XML is good at representing both text mark-up as well as data structures and the tooling around XML is mature and widespread.

Having said that, JSON has emerged as a popular serialization of hierarchical data structures—the “X” in AJAX. While we don't have the same watertight abstraction between JSON and MarkLogic’s internal data model today, we do provide a set of tools that allow you to efficiently and losslessly convert between JSON and the XML data model. Additionally, our REST and Java APIs allow you to store, retrieve, and even query tree structures that originated as JSON without having to think about this conversion step; the APIs handle this in the plumbing.

As for performance, there will be a little overhead converting between a JSON and XDM representation. However, I’d expect that to be negligible for most applications. The real benefits of XML will be in the expressiveness of XQuery, XPath, and XSLT in working with the data. There is no widespread equivalent to these in the JSON world today.

Comment: Thank you. We've experienced a significant performance overhead when storing documents in XML and then transforming them to JSON using XQuery. In some cases, a request which takes about 2 seconds is bloated to 12 seconds, given the transformation. I'll provide a code sample shortly, but in the meantime, is there anything that will explicitly slow down the conversion process, as regards data-structure, size of the response, etc.?

Comment: Yes, please post some code here or file an issue with our support organization. I’m very interested in understanding your use case.

Comment: Hi Justin, I've edited my original post to include a small code-snippet.

Comment: I've been informed by our XQuery guy that it was actually another issue causing the performance overhead, unrelated to JSON-transformation. In any case, do you have any opinion on the efficiency of the provided code-sample?

Answer (score 4):

MarkLogic is XML-native and does need to convert JSON to XML to store it in the database. There is a high-level JSON library to perform transformations. The main functions are `json:transform-to-json` and `json:transform-from-json`, and when configured correctly should provide lossless conversions.

I think the main difference from your example is whether you want to convert to XML using your own process or use MarkLogic's toolkit.

For more detailed information, see MarkLogic's docs:
http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/json

Answer (score 2):

One footnote:  The REST API (and thus the Java API wrapper around the REST API) provide a facade for the JSON conversion to XML -- that is, the APIs do the conversion to XML for you.

Usually, you don't need to think about the conversion except when you are creating range and geospatial indexes over the converted elements.

If you need to support JSON documents in your client, then the facade is convenient.

On the other hand, expressing the structure as JSON has no advantages for database operations and some limitations.  (For instance, XML has the standards-based, baked atomic data types, schema validation, and server processing with XQuery or XSLT.)  So, if you have complete control over the data structure, you might want to write it to the server as XML.

Answer (score 1):

As of MarkLogic 8 (February 2015), [JSON](http://developer.marklogic.com/features/json) is now a native data type, just like XML. This eliminates the needs for a translation layer for applications that want to work exclusively in JSON. In addition, we’ve added [JavaScript](http://developer.marklogic.com/features/javascript) as a first-class language in the database itself (using Google’s V8 engine). This means that you can write stored procedures, triggers, and even full HTTP applications with JavaScript that runs in the database, close to the data.

Comment: What is advantages/disadvantages storing data in json compared to xml format? I believe as database xml would do better than json? Or both will equally do the same job? If yes then json would be better since less storage and hence improve performance..

Comment: MarkLogic manages both JSON and XML internally as highly optimized trees. Thus the `<` and `{` are only relevant for parsing and serializing. When deciding between JSON and XML you should think about how your data will be used and the tools/skills that your developers will be using. The storage/performance differences are negligible compared to these.